# How to extract CSS3 filter functions from string with Regex

Tags: javascript, css, regex, filter

I'm working on a `RegEx` to extract CSS3 `filter` functions:

```js
let currentStyle = `blur(0em) drop-shadow(rgb(0, 0, 0) 0em 0em 0em) hue-rotate(85deg) grayscale(150%) brightness(90%) url(#mySVGFilter)`;

let fnReg = new RegExp('(^(blur|brightness|contrast|drop-shadow|hue-rotate|grayscale|invert|opacity|saturate|sepia|url).*(?:[(\)\s)|\)])$)');

// returns null or the entire string playing with other variations of the above RegEx
let matches = currentStyle.match(fnReg);
```

**Expected output**

```js
var matches = [
 `blur(0em)`,
 `drop-shadow(rgb(0, 0, 0) 0em 0em 0em)`,
 `hue-rotate(85deg)`,
 `grayscale(150%)`,
 `brightness(90%)`,
 `url(#mySVGFilter)`
]
```

**Problem**
I don't know how to make it actually work and how to simplify the RegEx, considering there are sub-groups like `rgb()` that have a similar pattern with other "main" groups.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Addis edited the post

Comment: You're going to have a pretty hard time doing this with a regex, considering that one of a filter function's arguments could be, say, a string (e.g. in `url('...')`), and the string's contents could have nested (and possibly unbalanced) parentheses and so forth. Have you considered using one of the many available CSS parsing libraries instead?

Comment: I don't expect `(` or quotes for `url()`, it might be something like `url(#someID)` or `url(http://path-to/#someID)`. I only need something quick and simple, as well as somewhat consistent. Also I'm counting on `filter` property being very very strict about valid values.

Comment: how about something like this `/[a-z-]+\(.*?\)(?=\s+[a-z-]+\(.*?\)|\s*$)/g` it's not that precise, but it should match the general pattern

Comment: @Thomas I would paste that into an answer and mark it down as solved, other improvements could come later with more community feedback.

Comment: It is not bullet proof, but for the example data perhaps split on `[ ](?=[^()]*\([ ]*[#\w])` https://regex101.com/r/fXQYnu/1 See https://rextester.com/QRQS16860

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas)'s comment, I came to a RegEx that actually works and I want to share it with everyone, so we can improve it even more.

```js
// Thomas' regex
let ThomasFnReg = 
/[a-z-]+\(.*?\)(?=\s+[a-z-]+\(.*?\)|\s*$)/g;

// my final RegEx
let fnReg = 
/(([a-z].*?)\(.*?\))(?=\s([a-z].*?)\(.*?\)|\s*$)/g;

// the possible target string
let targetString = `blur(0em) drop-shadow(rgb(0, 0, 0) 0em 0em 0em) hue-rotate(85deg) grayscale(150%) brightness(90%) url(#mySVGFilter)`;

// test
let matches0 = targetString.match(ThomasFnReg);

document.body.innerHTML += '<b>Thomas\'s RegEx results</b>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<ul>';
matches0.map(x=>document.body.innerHTML += `<li>${x}</li>`);
document.body.innerHTML += '</ul>';

document.body.innerHTML += '<hr>';

let matches1 = targetString.match(fnReg);
document.body.innerHTML += '<b>My RegEx results</b>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<ul>';
matches1.map(x=>document.body.innerHTML += `<li>${x}</li>`);
document.body.innerHTML += '</ul>';
```

```css
body {font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial; letter-spacing:0.02em}
```

Both expressions return somewhat usable results, pick yours and enjoy!